# Iam trying to update the state "Experience" but I didn't get updated value. please correct if my code is wrong

Tags: reactjs, setstate

am trying to calculate the year of experience so I Initialized state "Experience = 0" and I initialized the current year to the "currentDt" state

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        CurrentDt : new Date().getFullYear(),
        DOJ : 0,
        Experience : 0
    }
}
```

Getting user input for "DOJ" state and updating using setstate()

```
    GetJoiningDt = (event) =>{
    const DojValue = event.target.value;
   this.setState({
           DOJ :DojValue
       })
}
```

Below code for subtracting currentYear and DOJ year then trying to update "Experience" state by subtracted value`

```
    calculateExperience = ()=>{
    alert("Inside_calculateExperience");
    let a = this.state.CurrentDt;
    let b = this.state.DOJ;
    var ExpValue = a - b;        //2021-2015
    alert(ExpValue);             // 6
    this.setState({
        Experience : ExpValue     //0
    })
}
```

when I alert the value of "ExpValue" it shows value 6 but Inside setstate() its updating 0. and converting states to JSON.

```
    GetAsJSONData = () =>{
    console.log("JsonData");
    this.calculateExperience();
    let JsonData = {
        Experience : this.state.Experience
    }
    let showdata = JSON.stringify(JsonData);
    document.querySelector('label').textContent = showdata;
    document.write(showdata);

}


    render(){
    return(
        <form>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.DOJ} onChange= 
            {this.GetJoiningDt} placeholder="Year of DOJ" name="fullname" /> 
             <br/>  
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.GetAsJSONData}>Convert 
            Json</button><br></br>
            <label></label>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Comment: please upload whole code as this part seems ok.

Comment: Does this work for you `this.setState(prev => ({ Experience : prev..CurrentDt - prev.DOJ }))`?

Comment: @AmirhosseinEbrahimi No still Experience shows 0.

Comment: I think this whole thing is right. The problem is in form submission. After submitting it, the page reloads which resets the state. You should try submitting form with using preventDefault.

Comment: check my answer. I think that is the only problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consider Async and Await.
I made a sandbox version for you.
Please check the link below

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-water-9w238?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the page from reloading after the form is submitted as the react state is lost after page reload.

```
<form id='form'>
<input type='text'>
<button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to do that, then use `localstorage` object to store your state and then retain it after the form is submitted.